# How to create a custom clipboard format in a WinForms app

Tags: c#, .net, clipboard

Take a look at this image:

[image: img2]

The screenshot is generated by copying one of the contacts in your skype list. The data contains raw bytes containing information that skype apparently finds useful (in this case, the contact name, along with the size of the name).

I would like to accomplish this myself.

Here's the code I used in an attempt to copy to clipboard

```
byte[] bytes = new byte[] { 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20 };
Clipboard.SetData("My Data", bytes);
```

Which does copy to the clipboard. However, I get a DataObject entry along with some extra data added to it, rather than just raw bytes:

[image: img2]

The top half is what I see. The bottom half is when I take a screenshot of the screen. Notice that it is just raw bitmap data.

Can this be done in .NET?

Comment: Please see : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.clipboard.setdata(v=vs.110).aspx
SetData method requires the format but it seems you are feeding it "My Data" which does not seem to be a correct format. I think you may wanna use SetDataObject if the Data format will be unknown.

Comment: I did not see this remark at the bottom of the DataFormats page: `Add a new format name/ID number pair to the static list in this class, and to register the format with the Windows registry as a Clipboard format when you pass it the format name.` I will look into this and see how to register it as a format.

Comment: You already get a custom format.  It is the right kind of format, it can always be safely retrieved by whatever app accesses the Clipboard.  Automatically loading the required assembly and providing diagnostics if there's any mismatch.  Raw bytes can of course never accomplish that, there is no point in pursuing that at all.

Comment: @HansPassant The application that will be accessing the clipboard uses its own custom clipboard format (similar to the Bitmap entry, except its own entry). It doesn't accept data (as in, cannot paste) that has extra data added to it, which is why I'm trying to send raw bytes to the clipboard to emulate what the other application is doing. I would like to be able to see something similar to the Bitmap object which is just raw, bitmap data.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The extra bytes are serialization headers. See this [note](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.clipboard(v=vs.110).aspx) from the MSDN documentation on the `Clipboard` class (emphasis mine):

> An object must be serializable for it to be put on the Clipboard. If
>   you pass a non-serializable object to a Clipboard method, the method
>   will fail without throwing an exception. See
>   System.Runtime.Serialization for more information on serialization. **If
>   your target application requires a very specific data format, the
>   headers added to the data in the serialization process may prevent the
>   application from recognizing your data. To preserve your data format,
>   add your data as a Byte array to a MemoryStream and pass the
>   MemoryStream to the SetData method**.

So the solution is to do this:

```
byte[] bytes = new byte[] { 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20 };
MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(bytes);
Clipboard.SetData("My Data", stream);
```